# select tab with text link

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I have a question regarding a tabs script (not jquery ui tabs). I want to select the tab with a normal text link on top of the page. The tabs are at the bottom of the page. I was hoping this could be achieved with an anchor, but no....

The link:

```
<a class="reviewslink" href="#reviews">blabla</a>
```

The script for clicking on the tabs itself:

```
$('.tabs a').click(function(){
        var tabs = $(this).closest('.tabs');
        var pages = tabs.next();
        tabs.find('a').closest('li').removeClass('active');
        pages.find('.page').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        pages.find('.page.'+$(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active');
        return false;
    });
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
          <ul>
            <li class="active"><a rel="bestellen" href="#">Test</a></li>
            <li><a rel="ruilen" href="#" name="maattabel">Test1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tabsPages">
         <div class="page bestellen active"></div>
         <div class="page ruilen"></div>
        </div>
```

I tried this below but that doesn't work, obvious. I can't figure out how I should do this.

```
  $('.reviewslink').click(function() { // bind click event to link

        var tabs = $(this).closest('.tabs');
        var pages = tabs.next();
        tabs.find('a').closest('li').removeClass('active');
        pages.find('.page').removeClass('active');

        tabs.select('select', 3).addClass('active');
        pages.find('.page.reviews.'+$(this).attr('rel')).addClass('active');

        return false;
  });
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your tabs are at the bottom, I think closest won't help. Because , closest get the first element by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. And I don't think that .reviewslink is nested inside .tabs. Correct?

Comment: @axel.michel: .reviewslink is a text link on top of the page and not within .tabs! Can this be done with location.hash?

Comment: it depends on your tab script.

Comment: @axel.michel: I've updated my question with the complete code. I tried several things today but I can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example HTML does not seam to be complete and/or consistent, but I think I understand what you are trying to do. How about sending a click event to the tab?

```
$('.reviewslink').click(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
    var tab = $('a[name=' + name + ']');
    tab.click();
    return false;
}
```

For this code to work you need to add `name="reviews"` to the `a` element of the tab that you want to be selected when clicking the link.

Comment: Thx that seems to work. Only problem now is that the anchor doesn't work anymore. So when I click the link the page doesn't jump down to the actual tab. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: If you remove the `return false` from the function the event is no longer consumed and the browser default action "jump to the anchor" takes place.